# How to load a page quickly that contains slow-loading social network content?

Tags: html, lazy-loading

Right now I have a  with social media icons  and they take for ever to load,the code for these buttons is near the top of the code so it is slowing everything else down i think.

Isnt there a way to have where i want the buttons to go but put the codes to the buttons right before

so the class x is just a place holder and the button code right before  will fill that space AFTER the rest of the page loads?

Comment: Please read the entire [Web Standards Curriculum](http://www.w3.org/community/webed/wiki/Main_Page) before posting further questions.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the document `onReady` event to run Javascript code when all the rest is done loading. In jQuery, `$(document).ready(funct)` will do the trick.

Comment: non coder here. is the script where would i put the code you said to use? <script src="http://www.stumbleupon.com/hostedbadge.php?s=2&r=http://{URL}/{$story_url}"></script>

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
     //for example you can do this :
    document.write("<script type='text/javascript' src='something.js'></script>")
});
<script><br/>
```

this will loads you scripts in body after other elemnts loaded but if this solves your problem you should do write your script in some other element to ignore infinite loop of $(document).ready() like this perhaps : 
     document.getElementById('myDiv').innerHTML="";

Comment: like this then???<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
     <script src="stumbleupon.com/hostedbadge.php?s=2&r=http:/{URL}/{$story_url}"></‌​script>
});
<script>

Comment: That loads even slower. any other way to do it?